# Changes made to install.wim file is not in effect

Tags: windows, windows-server-2022, dism, wim

I am using the DISM command to mount the install.wim and adding few folders and file to the root folder c:\ and them committed the image file.
then creating a bootable ISO with the modified the WIM file. but the folders and file I added to the image is not visible after the windows installation.

what am I missing here?

below is sequence of the steps

1. Extract the original windows bootalble ISO into a folder "S:\MS Windows Server\Win2022"
2. mount the WIM file using

> dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:"S:\MS Windows Server\Win2022\sources\install.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:I:\Mount2022

3. open the I:\Mount2022 in explorer and added few folders into it
4. used the below command to commit the image

> dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:I:\Mount2022 /Commit

5. use anyburn/imageburn tools to create an ISO with the modified WIM file
6. boot the server using the ISO and complete the setup.

Comment: It could be helpful to add the commands and steps you executed when trying to achieve your result.

Comment: thanks, I have added some more info now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to `/Export-Image` once to make my changes actually applied to the installation. It used to be not necessary. I am figuring out why.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But in my case, I was mounting the wrong Index.

Answer (score 0):

I was mounting the wrong Index.

When mounting ISO which supports multiple editions, use get-imageinfo to find the index information before mounting them.

> dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:"I:\install.wim"